# How can I see if I have reached beginning of file?

Tags: c, file

I have a task to rewrite the Unix system function `tail`. My algorithm works in the following way:

I `lseek` to the end of the file, enter a loop, move the file descriptor a bit back, read a couple of bytes, and if I find any new lines, I increase the counter. Once, I get 10 new lines ( I think it should be 11, but the thing is not finished yet and this works for me for now ), I leave the loop.

---

If the file has less than 10 new lines, I get into an infinite loop, because of the way I wrote it.

Is there a way to see if I have reached the beginning of the file, so I can leave the loop then?

Code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int fd;
    off_t offset = 10;
    size_t size = 10;
    unsigned char buff[10];
    int new_line_counter = 0;
    off_t total_offset = 0;//dont mind this
    fd = open("a.txt", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }
    lseek(fd,0,SEEK_END);
    while (new_line_counter < 10)
    {
        lseek(fd,-offset,SEEK_CUR);
        total_offset+=10;//dont mind this
        for(int i = 0; i<10;i++)
        {
            if(buff[i]=='\n')
            {   
                if(new_line_counter==10)break;
                new_line_counter++;
                //printf("%d",new_line_counter);
            
            }
        }
        read(fd,buff,size);
        lseek(fd,-offset,SEEK_CUR);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the return value of `lseek`. It will return the current file position, or, -1 on error.

You first `lseek(fd,0,SEEK_END)` will give you the file size.

Use that to keep track the current file position (and make sure that to adjust 'offset' so that `lseek(fd,-offset,SEEK_CUR);` will never seek before file begin.

This is necessary, otherwise you might miss the first line.

Comment: @andreas-h, i don't think the OP should save the file size from his first `lseek()` because files can grow as you watch them.

Comment: @mr.fixit  But file growth will not affect the current file pointer. Behavior with SEEK_CUR or SEEK_SET is same, whether file grows or not (each open file maintains its own file pointer).

Comment: @andreas-h, you're right for the task at hand (not offsetting back earlier than BOF). in my head, i was jumping ahead to implementing the `-f` option of system's `tail`. I shouldn't do that!

Answer (score 0):

`lseek()` returns a value, it's either the new offset or -1. Check for that value like this:

```
    while (new_line_counter < 10)
    {
        if (-1==lseek(fd,-offset,SEEK_CUR)) break;
```